# getPrimaryClip() is returning null object reference

Tags: java, android, mobile, mobile-development

I am trying to make an app that will get the user's clipboard with the press of a button on a notification. The code I have in my notification broadcast receiver is here:

```
if (intent.getAction().equals(SEND_CLIPBOARD_ACTION)) {
            ClipboardManager clipboardManager =
                    (ClipboardManager) context.getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
            ClipData primaryClip = clipboardManager.getPrimaryClip();
            if (primaryClip.getItemCount() > 0) {
                CharSequence text = primaryClip.getItemAt(0).coerceToText(context);
                if (text != null) {
                    String clipboard = clipboardManager.getPrimaryClip().toString();
                    Utils utils = Utils.getInstance(context);
                    utils.getPairedPC(intent.getStringExtra(PC_ADDRESS_KEY))
                            .setClipboardCache(clipboard);
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Clipboard Sent!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Clipboard Empty!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
```

The button works fine, except when it gets to the line where it checks if there are items in the primary clip, it gives me a null pointer exception. I read on the docs that this is because you can only get a user's clipboard data from the main thread. Is there any possible way to get a user's clipboard data in the background without requiring them to go into the app?

Comment: No, reading clipboard from background was disabled for privacy and security, only exception is currently selected input method (keyboard).

Comment: @Pawel Crap. Well thank you for the help! I guess I just gonna have to find some other way.